# GAE/Java: Are Transactions Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Forgive me if it's an obvious question, but I read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) from top to bottom, and I'm still not sure what is the answer to this question:

If I have a datastore transaction that reads the number of a counter and increments it, can I be certain that 2 parallel servlets won't interleave each other? In other words, the docs only say that the transaction either fails or succeed atomically, but it does not say the transaction locks the data for other servlets, so what happens when 2 servlets access the same entity at the same time?

If indeed the transactions are not thread-safe, should I just use `synchronized` when accessing shared datastore counters?

Comment: synchronized only works in a single JVM (roughly) and won't help you when AppEngine spins up several JVMs to serve your app. How does your current transaction code look? How many queries are you expecting to hit your counter? Might be worth to look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are "thread-safe" as long as you do writes on for entities that have a common ancestor.

Take a look at the GAE low level datastore API and once you understand how Entities work, it's pretty straightforward.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities